# Cache control with webpack and node express

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, caching, webpack

My workflow is as follows:

1) I build my front-end using`webpack` with all the cool `[chunkhash]` to make sure my generated files have different names when there are changes and therefore busting the cache and finish with something like:

```
app.asdf4354234asdfchunkhashname.js
app.asdf4354234asdfchunkhashname.css
index.html
```

Awesome!

2) I then have a node express server to serve the above pages and an API, short version:

```
var express = require('express');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client'))); // Where the wekback files are located after the build
...app.listen(...
```

So great, my JS and CSS have unique names for each versions, but the problem is that `index.html` gets cached and so the browser doesn't notice the new JS/CSS files. I don't think changing the name of `index.html` and having node filter the requests to redirect to `newIndex.html` is a great solution.

**Question:** Anything wrong in my workflow? How do I not cache `index.html` or let the browser know there is a new version of my files?

Comment: Why does it get cached? Express sets `max-age=0` by default, and supports both `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since`, so I'm not sure why a browser would use a cached version.

Comment: @robertklep Me neither :) I saw in the response headers 
`Cache-Control:public, max-age=0
Date:Thu, 13 Apr 2017 13:01:13 GMT
ETag:W/"1bb6-15b6748613a"
Last-Modified:Thu, 13 Apr 2017 12:27:28 GMT` Thought I was doing something wrong...

Comment: But if you reload the page after running Webpack, you get the old `index.html`? Can you check the request that the browser makes, and what the response from the server is (either a 200 or a 304)?